# Stuck on an elementary based probability question.

Tags: probability

A fair coin is tossed 3 times.

What is the probability that you get 2 or more heads given at least one head?

So I'm really stumped how to approach this problem, but here's what I did:

Let P(A) = Probability of at least one head.

Let P(B) = Probability of at least 2 or more heads.

We need to find P(B|A) = P(B and A) / P(A) by definition.

P(A) = 1 - P(No Head) = $1$ - [$(1/2)^3$] = $7/8$.

P(B) = P(2 head) + P(3 head) = $(1/2)^2$ + $(1/2)^3$ = $3/8$

But P(A) and P(B) are not independent events. So I am confused how to compute P(B and A).

What is wrong with my approach here?

Comment: Yes they are not independent events. But one of them happen implies the other one must happen, i.e. one of them is the subset of other. So the intersection of them will equal to the subset.

Comment: You could start more concretely by considering all cases.  Of the possible (equiprobable) sequences, how many of them have at least one head?  Of these, how many have at least 2 heads?  The answer follows from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right with your formula. Which is to say, $P(B | A) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)}$.

You have calculated $P(A)$ correctly: It is $\dfrac{7}{8}$.

To find $P(B \cap A)$, let us recognize the nature of this event: Note that $B$ is "more than 2 heads occur" and $A$ is "at least one head occurs". *However, if $B$ has happened, $A$ has already happened*!

That is to say, $B \cap A = B$. Then, all we are calculating is $\dfrac{P(B)}{P(A)} = \dfrac{4}{7}$ (your calculation of $P(B)$ is wrong, I'll leave you to see the error).

I  know it is a little difficult to see why $A \cap B = B$, but if you are unable to fathom this, then do reply.

Comment: I like your response.

My intuition behind B and A = B is because if B and A were independent then P(B and A) = P(B) * P(A), but in our case P(A) always happens, so P(A) would be just 1 (or 100% chance), and we simply get P(B).

I guess I was on the right track but I made a mistake computing P(B). By the defn of union P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A and B), or rather just P(A) since P(A and B) = P(B) which cancels out the other P(B). 

I think I get it now. Do you agree with my reasoning?

Comment: I perfectly agree with your reasoning. It's good to reason elaborately, especially when you are just starting out in a topic.

Answer (score 0):

Here total no. Of events =8-1=7 (since we cannot have 3 tails)

We can have 2 heads in 3 ways.

We can have 3 heads in 1 way.

Total no.of favourable ways=4

Hence, Probability = 4/7